# Search for a file that matches a keyword, then attach it to an email

Tags: powershell

I've written a PowerShell script that searches a folder for a file that matches a keyword eg `Japan` and then adds the file as an attachment to an email.

The email sends correctly, however the file isn't attached.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Powershell.Admin -ErrorAction 
SilentlyContinue

$dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir | -Filter "$keyword" -Recurse | Select-Object 
$keyword = "Japan"
$mailboxdata = (Get-MailboxStatistics | select DisplayName,TotalItemSize,TotalDeletedItemSize, ItemCount, LastLoggedOnUserAccount, LastLogonTime)
$mailboxdata | Export-Csv "$file"
$smtpServer = "192.168.1.100"
$att = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From = "email@mail.com"
$msg.To.Add("email@othermail.com")
$msg.Subject = "Notification from email server"
$msg.Body = "Attached is the email server mailbox report for Japan"

$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$att.Dispose()
```

Comment: Move `$keyword = "Japan"` above `$file = [...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've modified a script from another source (that sends Mailbox Statistics from Microsoft Exchange) and you've left in parts of it that you do not need.

```
$dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
$keyword = "Japan"
$smtpServer = "192.168.1.100"

$file = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$keyword*" -Recurse

$att = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
$msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

$msg.From = "email@mail.com"
$msg.To.Add("email@othermail.com")
$msg.Subject = "Notification from email server"
$msg.Body = "Attached is the email server mailbox report for Japan"

$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
$smtp.Send($msg)
$att.Dispose()
```

---

I would use `Send-MailMessage` instead as it's syntax is much easier to use:

```
$dir = "C:\Users\user\Desktop"
$keyword = "Japan"

$Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$keyword*" -Recurse

$From = "email@mail.com"
$To = "email@othermail.com"
$Subject = "Files matching: $keyword"
$Body = "Attached is the file for: $keyword"
$SMTPServer = "192.168.1.100"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment.FullName
```

Comment: I'd remove the pipe symbol in front of `-Filter`

Comment: $Attachment = Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*$keyword*" -Recurse 

This doesnt work still and I cant figure it out

Comment: You don't need any of those lines, the snapin you were loading is for managing Exchange and is not needed to send an email. You've also removed both asterisks from the filter. Did you actually try either of my examples? If so what error message did you get?

Comment: Send-MailMessage : Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Janpan.xlsx'.
At C:\Users\users\Documents\Projects_user\Email24try.ps1:12 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -S ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Send-MailMessage], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage

Comment: It seems to be looking in the folder that the script is located for the file instead of the directory

Comment: I'm not near a computer to test, but try updating `-Attachments $Attachment.FullName`

Comment: @OisínJohnMcHugh did updating the attachment work? If so please click the checkmark/tick to the left of my answer. Doing this helps others find a good answer to the question if they search in future.